# How to install RHadoop on Ubuntu Natty 11.04 machine?

Tags: r, rhadoop

I need to install RHadoop on my ubuntu natty 11.04 machine. I tried doing these commands "apt-get install r-base" but i am getting unmet dependencies

```
root@cldx-1063-961:/home/rhadoop/dependency# apt-get install r-base

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 g++-4.5 : Depends: gcc-4.5-base (= 4.5.3-12ubuntu2) but 4.5.2-8ubuntu2 is to be installed
           Depends: gcc-4.5 (= 4.5.3-12ubuntu2) but 4.5.2-8ubuntu4 is to be installed
           Depends: libstdc++6-4.5-dev (= 4.5.3-12ubuntu2) but 4.5.2-8ubuntu4 is to be installed
           Depends: libgmp10 but it is not installable
           Depends: libmpfr4 (>= 3.1.0) but 3.0.0-7 is to be installed
 gcc-4.5 : Depends: gcc-4.5-base (= 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) but 4.5.2-8ubuntu2 is to be installed
           Depends: cpp-4.5 (= 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) but 4.5.2-8ubuntu2 is to be installed
 gfortran-4.2 : Depends: gcc-4.2 (= 4.2.4-1ubuntu3) but it is not installable
                Depends: libmpfr1ldbl but it is not installable
 libblas-dev : Depends: libblas3gf (= 1.2-1.3ubuntu3) but 1.2-7 is to be installed
 libbz2-dev : Depends: libbz2-1.0 (= 1.0.4-2ubuntu4.2) but 1.0.5-6ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libgcc1 : Depends: gcc-4.5-base (= 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) but 4.5.2-8ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libgfortran3 : Depends: gcc-4.5-base (= 4.5.1-7ubuntu2) but 4.5.2-8ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libgomp1 : Depends: gcc-4.5-base (= 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) but 4.5.2-8ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libstdc++6 : Depends: gcc-4.5-base (= 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) but 4.5.2-8ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-4.5-dev : Depends: gcc-4.5-base (= 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) but 4.5.2-8ubuntu2 is to be installed
                      Depends: g++-4.5 (= 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) but 4.5.3-12ubuntu2 is to be installed
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 2.15.2-1natty0) but 2.6.2-2 is to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 2.15.2-1natty0) but 2.6.2-2 is to be installed
          Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: r-doc-html but it is not going to be installed
 r-base-dev : Depends: libjpeg62-dev but it is not installable
              Depends: libncurses5-dev but it is not installable
              Depends: libpcre3-dev but it is not installable
              Depends: libpng12-dev but it is not installable
              Depends: libreadline5-dev but it is not installable
              Depends: zlib1g-dev but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Please help me out with steps to install it. Any of your help would be greatly appreciated !!!

Comment: This should not happen and indicates that your software sources lists are messed up. You need to make sure that (1) entries in /etc/apt/sources.list are consistent (point to the same repository), (2) no additional lists are being read (e.g. in /etc/apt/sources.list.d) and then (3) apt-get update and try again.

Comment: This is most definitely an Ubuntu question.  It's got nothing to do with `R` .  Given that 11.04 is not (AFAIK) a 'long-term support' version, you might be better off with a fresh install of an LTS version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks  neilfws...I have added "deb http://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu natty/" in sources.list. Is is this correct ? can you help me with sources.list for ubuntu natty ?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to update your system to Ubuntu 12.04 (LTS) & then try to install r-base,latest R version, rhdfs,rmr etc.

After updated to 12.04, try following commands & packages

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get build-dep r-base
sudo apt-get install r-base r-recommended r-base-dev
```

Install rmr & rhdfs by reading instructions  from here [link-1](http://jugnu-life.blogspot.com/2013/03/install-rhadoop-on-hadoop-cluster.html) [link-2](http://www.adaltas.com/blog/2012/05/19/hadoop-and-r-is-rhadoop/) [link-3](http://nerdslearning.wordpress.com/2012/06/05/an-installation-guide-for-installing-rhadoop-on-mac-os-x-10-7-4-with-hadoop-1-0-1/) [link-4](http://ashokharnal.wordpress.com/2013/08/25/installing-r-rhadoop-and-rstudio-over-cloudera-hadoop-ecosystem/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to log in as root and then do "R CMD INSTALL" for the separate packages.